# react native access environmental variables on MS appCenter

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have a working pipeline with react native on [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms) CI/CD.

Now I need to have [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/variables/).

How can they be accessed from JS?

Comment: hi Manuel, did you find the solution?